# ¿Cual es la forma más eficiente de llamar a una función ignorando el argumento que recibe en Python?

Tags: python, c

Me encuentro en un escenario como este (se que no tiene sentido, pero es para ejemplificar):

```
import itertools

repeat_true = itertools.repeat(True)
value = next(itertools.takewhile(lambda key:next(repeat_true), [1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

He notado que esto implica colocar un lambda en medio, lo que demora un poco la iteración. Pero en realidad, en el fondo, solo quiero ejecutar `repeat_true.__next__` sin pasarle ningún argumento.

**Primer idea**

Obtener el objeto code de dicho. Terminé leyendo una respuesta que indica que los objetos built-in no tienen dicho objeto.

**Segunda idea**

Como Python está hecho en c, consideré el uso de ctypes junto a mis limitados conocimientos en dicho lenguaje para acelerar la llamada, lo funcionó parcialmente:

```
import itertools
import ctypes

KEY = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool)

repeat_true = KEY(itertools.repeat(True).__next__)

value = next(itertools.takewhile(repeat_true, [1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Por lo que leí, las funciones c pueden recibir infinitos argumentos, lo cual me va como anillo al dedo.

Pero si le paso ciertos tipos de argumentos, ctypes trata, sin exito, de transformarlos. Arrojando un error.

Intenté ver como crear parametros con valores default, pero al parecer, no existe eso en c.

¿Hay algún truco, tanto con ctypes como en python puro, para hacer una función eficiente (es decir, rapida)?

---

*Edit*

Me han informado que desde Python 3.11, Python es adaptativo y trata de simplificar el resultado. En tal escenario, usar lambda _:next(iterator) resulte claramente simplificado.

Sin embargo, a la fecha de esta pregunta, es una tecnología muy reciente, por lo que busco una solución para versiones de Python sin esta caracteristica.

Comment: Por que el voto negativo? Incluso mostré mis intentos de resolverlo

Comment: Perdón si mi comentario es spam, pero le debo las gracias al votante positivo c:

Comment: ctypes es una ayuda para manejar tipos de C desde python. Puede ser más eficiente en memoria, pero no mejora el rendimiento. Python está optimizado para usar iteradores y generadores, sobre todo con funciones propias como `sum()`, `any()` o `all()`. Estas optimizaciones son aún mayores con python 3.12 y sus [_comprensiones en línea_](https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html#pep-709-comprehension-inlining),. Poco más se puede ganar bajando de nivel a C. Por otro lado, si quieres fijar argumentos en una llamada prueba a usar `functools.partial()`.

Comment: Ya veo. Gracias por el aviso. El problema con functools.partial, es que usa python puro, haciendo que haya una "doble llamada", al igual que un lambda. Busco usar ctypes para ver si puedo tener una versión más eficiente de dicha clase.

Comment: Sigues pensando en python como un sistema estático; pero el intérprete de python es _dinámico_ y _adaptativo_ ([desde la versión 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#pep-659-specializing-adaptive-interpreter)). Si detecta un _invariante_ en el código que se repite, lo intenta simplificar por su resultado intermedio o por llamadas directas a C. Por supuesto, ni se acerca al rendimiento de un código de bajo nivel como C o rust, pero te da una idea del poco margen que tienes para optimizar la ejecución de código dentro del intérprete.

Comment: "desde la versión 3.11" es demasiado reciente por el momento. Aun así, está bueno que lo hayan mejorado. Así que busco una solución para 3.10 para abajo. Gracias por decirmelo!

Comment: Probablemente si quieres tomar ventaja de C debas programar el procedimiento en C y llamarlo desde Python.

Answer (score 0):

Ya estás ignorando el valor de la variable pasada como argumento, pero tu código podría ser más eficiente simplemente no usando un iterador para devolver el valor. Puedes devolver True directamente en el lambda (que obligatoriamente tiene que recibir el parámetro):

```py
value = next(itertools.takewhile(lambda Key:True, [1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

O declarar una función, que también reciba el parámetro y simplemente lo ignore, y pasar esa función como predicado:

```py
def alwaysTrue(x):
    return True
    
value = next(itertools.takewhile(alwaysTrue, [1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

En cualquiera de los casos, va a ser más rápido, pues no tiene que usar todos los mecanismos internos del iterador para obtener el siguiente `True`, sino que lo obtiene directamente.

Finalmente, solo comentar que ignorar un argumento es algo que no puedes decidir desde el punto donde se llama a la función. Quizás es solo un tema de como redactaste la pregunta, pero considero importante aclararlo, pues genera confusión.

La única que puede decidir ignorar el argumento, es la función misma, sea una función declarada formalmente, un lambda, o cualquier otra forma de *función ejecutable*. Desde la llamada, no tienes de otra que pasarle el argumento si lo requiere.

Si tú estás escribiendo la llamada, puedes intentar pasarle `None`, pero no puedes dejar de pasarle *algo* al argumento.

Y, así como en tu ejemplo, dónde es la biblioteca la que va a realizar la llamada, no tienes de otra que recibir el argumento en la función.  Ciertamente esto va a *gastar* algo de tiempo, algunos bytes en el Stack o registros establecidos en el procesador, y los ciclos de reloj que esto tome, pero eso, hasta dónde sé, no tienes forma de evitarlo.

Es decir, no tienes forma de escribir una función que sea llamada con algunos parámetros, pero no reciba ninguno.

Por ejemplo:

```py
def alwaysTrue():
    return True
    
value = next(itertools.takewhile(alwaysTrue, [1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Va a elevar una excepción:

```
TypeError: alwaysTrue() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! He hecho pruebas en un escenario mas complejo y, para mi sorpresa, el enfoque de c es más lento que el lambda (probablemente, algo que no se de ctypes). Pero usar lambdas y funciones directamente es todavía más lento que usar la mezcla de iterador y lambda. El escenario que presenté fue un ejemplo sin sentido (el mismo efecto se consigue con next(iter(iterable))) para ilustrar lo que deseaba realizar. Seguiré haciendo pruebas a ver si encuentro una forma de interactuar mejor con c y esperando más respuestas, y si no, publicaré el resultado que obtuve.

Comment: ctypes es una ayuda para manejar tipos de C desde python. Puede ser más eficiente en memoria, pero no mejora el rendimiento. Python está optimizado para usar iteradores y generadores, sobre todo con funciones propias como `sum()`, `any()` o `all()`. Estas optimizaciones son aún mayores con python 3.12 y sus [_comprensiones en línea_](https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html#pep-709-comprehension-inlining),. Poco más se puede ganar bajando de nivel a C. Por otro lado, si quieres fijar argumentos en una llamada prueba a usar `functools.partial()`.